# Hot to add new line \r\n and tabs in PHP DOM Document output?

Tags: php, xml, dom, html-parsing

I make simple parser for HTML using PHP DOM and i have problem with new lines (\r\n) in my output. Here is my code (i know it may be poor quality but it almost works and i'am beginner ;) )

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('page_1_second.html');

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHtml('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>'.$html);
libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);

$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname = 'row1h';
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
$tmp_dom = new DOMDocument();

foreach($nodes as $node)
{
    $tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($node,true));
}
$innerHTML = trim($tmp_dom->saveHTML());

$output = new DOMDocument();
$internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$output->loadHtml('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>'.$innerHTML);
libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);

foreach($output->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link)
{   
    echo
    '<topic_title>'.$link->nodeValue.'</topic_title>'.
    '<br>'.'/r/n'.
        '<topic_desc>'.$link->getAttribute('title').'</topic_desc>'.
    '<br><br>'; 
}

?>
```

Code above give me output with \r\n as text but i want new line:

```
<topic_title>Title ONE</topic_title><br>\r\n<topic_desc>DESC1</topic_desc><br><br><topic_title>Title two</topic_title><br>\r\n<topic_desc>DESC 2</topic_desc><br><br><topic_title>Title 3</topic_title><br>\r\n<topic_desc>DESC 3</topic_desc><br><br>
```

Im trying and i cant to get output to looks like this:

```
<topic_title>Title ONE</topic_title><br>
    <topic_desc>DESC1</topic_desc>

<topic_title>Title two</topic_title><br>
    <topic_desc>DESC 2</topic_desc><br>

<topic_title>Title 3</topic_title><br>
    <topic_desc>DESC 3</topic_desc><br><br>
```

Im trying `formatOutput = true;` but it's not working.

Anyone can help me to solve this probem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use double quotes to have escape sequences interpreted.

Have you tried using the double quotes " " rather than single quotes ' ' ?

Comment: This is more of a comment, an answer would more state what the problem was than ask a question.

Comment: OMG! I feel so shame - i forgot the basic rules of PHP that string between "double quotes" is interpreted and between signe is ingnored. Many thanks!